# Can't resolve $element after minification

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-material, webpack-dev-server, apache-karaf

I've got a strange bug that only appears when running my web appliction in karaf but not on the webpack-dev-server. When running the web app from Karaf when I open the dialog, I get this error in the browser console

```
angular.js:14516 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n

The component is responsible for displaying a table. The columns should be editable so i've implemented a stock dialog from the angular material demos. See -> https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog and a multi select with the option to search -> https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select

Here follows the code:

```
    ctrl.editColumns = (event) => {
      $mdDialog.show({
        template: require('./edit-column-dialog.template.html'),
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        scope: $scope,
        preserveScope: true,
        controller: EditColumnsDialogController
      })
    }

    function EditColumnsDialogController ($element) {
      ctrl.searchTerm = ''
      ctrl.copySelectedColumns = ctrl.selectedColumns

      // The md-select directive eats keydown events for some quick select
      // logic. Since we have a search input here, we don't need that logic.
      $element.find('input').on('keydown', (ev) => {
        ev.stopPropagation()
      })
    }
```

I use $element for the reason detailed in the comment above. What I can't get my head around is that this works fine on the web pack dev server. The only difference between the settings for web pack are:

```
// Add build specific plugins
if (isProd) {
  config.plugins.push(

  // Only emit files when there are no errors
  new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

  // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true
  }),

  // Copy assets from the public folder
  // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
    from: path.join(__dirname, '/app/public')
  }])
)}
```

Any answers are much appreciated.. or suggestions for isolating the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minifiers break code that uses [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation). Instead, use [`$inject` Property Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation):

```
  //USE $inject property annotation
  EditColumnsDialogController.$inject = ["$element"];

  function EditColumnsDialogController ($element) {
      ctrl.searchTerm = ''
      ctrl.copySelectedColumns = ctrl.selectedColumns

      // The md-select directive eats keydown events for some quick select
      // logic. Since we have a search input here, we don't need that logic.
      $element.find('input').on('keydown', (ev) => {
        ev.stopPropagation()
      })
  }
```

From the Docs:

> #### Implicit Annotation
>
> **Careful:** If you plan to [minify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) your code, your service names will get renamed and break your app.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Implicit Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation)

Comment: Thanks for that. It's interesting that if I remove the implicit annotation and just use the $inject property annotation that it doesn't work - I need to use both!